# Setting 'Select' Permission on 100+ tables in a database

Tags: sql-server-2012

I got the 'Select permission denied' error for some of my tables in a db.

In MS SQL Server 2012, setting 'Select' Permission on 1 table is easy. I just right click on the table > Properties > Permissions > Select the User/Role and tick the 'Select' Permission in the 'Explicit' tab below.

But I want to do that for over a 100 tables. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without while loop:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Sql = ''

select @Sql = @Sql +
    'grant select on '+
   s.name + '.' + o.name + ' to [domain\user] go' + CHAR(10)
from sys.objects o
join sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
where o.type = 'U' and s.name = 'dbo'

PRINT @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the list of tables you want from `sys.objects`, then loop through and execute `grant` on each table. Here's an example:

```
select 
   s.name + '.' + o.name schemaQualifiedTableName, 
   row_number() over (order by o.name) Id 
into #tables
from sys.objects o
join sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
where o.type = 'U' and s.name = 'dbo'

declare @counter int 
set @counter = 1

while exists(select * from #tables where id = @counter)
begin

    declare @sql as varchar(4000)

    select @sql = 'grant select on ' + schemaQualifiedTableName + ' to [domain\user] go' from #tables where id = @counter

    print @sql
    --exec (@sql)

    set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Quick and Dirty way would be creating a new database role and granting it select to the dbo squema (assuming that those tables are in the dbo scheme). Of course it's not the best security practice, a better practice would be granting that role to each table it needs and then include users in the role.
Before going to any solution you should define what level of security do you want to keep.

Hope this helps.